# Tidyverse: Why does selection helper piped to across() throw note/warning/error about external vector when placing helper inside across does not?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, across

Piping (the value of) a selection helper (`matches()`, `contains()`, `starts_with()`, `ends_with()`) to the `across()` function behaves differently from putting the selection helper inside the parentheses of `across()`.

- Why does this happen?
- Is this the expected behavior or a bug?

### Reproduce

```
library(dplyr)

# Very simple function: returns input
self = function(x){x}

# Data to manipulate
dtemp = tibble(var = 1:2)

# No note/warning/error when selection helper is inside across()
dtemp %>% mutate(across(matches("var"), self))

# Note/warning/error when selection helper is piped to across()
dtemp %>% mutate(matches("var") %>% across(self))
```

### Observed behavior

The last line causes R to print

```
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(.)` instead of `.` to silence this message.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
This message is displayed once per session.
```

Note that **this message is only printed once per session**, so you must restart R to see it again (unless there is some other way to reset the counter that controls this printing).

The penultimate command (with `matches()` inside `across()`) does not cause R to print the note.

### Expected behavior

The last two commands will behave identically.

### Additional info

- dplyr version: 1.0.6
- tidyverse version: 1.3.1

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_0.5.0      assertthat_0.2.1 utf8_1.2.1       crayon_1.4.1    
 [5] R6_2.5.0         DBI_1.1.1        lifecycle_1.0.0  magrittr_2.0.1  
 [9] pillar_1.6.1     cli_2.5.0        rlang_0.4.11     rstudioapi_0.13 
[13] vctrs_0.3.8      generics_0.1.0   ellipsis_0.3.2   tools_4.0.3     
[17] glue_1.4.2       purrr_0.3.4      compiler_4.0.3   pkgconfig_2.0.3 
[21] tidyselect_1.1.1 tibble_3.1.2
```

Comment: It is not an error, but I believe the documentation says that it will be transitioned to a warning in the future and then eventually transition into an error. I said “note/warning/error” to make the question more useful to people in the future.

Comment: I think most users understand `a %>% b` to be equivalent to `b(a)`, but perhaps `a %>% b` evaluates `a` and then applies `b()` to the value returned from evaluating `a` while `b(a)` evaluates `a` in an environment somehow determined by `b()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`matches` returns a character vector. In a recent `dplyr` release, `all_of` was introduced to remove ambiguity.  Suppose you have a `data.frame` with two columns `x` and `y`
Further, suppose you have a variable `x = 'y'`. Now if you `select(x)`, do you mean the column `x` or the column `y`? `all_of(x)` would remove this ambiguity. So when you pipe `matches` to `across`, it looks like you are selecting a character vector named `.`. The reason for this is that evaluating a selection helper itself just returns a vector as an argument to .cols. This is the basic principle of R pipes and inputs. You can test this out with `rlang::quo`. if `f <- function(x) rlang::quo(x)`, then running `f(1)` is different from running `1 %>% f`. First returns a quoted 1 the second returns a quoted `.`. So, if we evaluate `across(<selection-helper>)` this is the same as evaluating `f(1)`, while `<selection-helper> %>% across()` is the same as `1 %>% f()`. For across the latter looks like a variable `.` which has a dedicated environment containing its values (hence it looks like a vector called `.`.

To clarify lets look at the outputs as follows:

```r
library(magrittr)
f <- function(x) rlang::enquo(x)
f(1)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^1
#> env:  empty
1 %>% 
    f()
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^.
#> env:  00000000166DD798
`%>%`(1,f)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^.
#> env:  00000000165176F0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
The first output captures and quotes `1` (which has no environment it is not an object/symbol), while using the pipe command, we store the values of the `lhs` in an environment with the symbol/name `.`. The value `1` is now contained in that environment. This is the essence of how the pipe works. Store `lhs` value(s) in an environment called `.`, then put it as the first argument in the `rhs` (unless `.` is put somewhere else) and evaluate it.

Hence, it throws the warning as it looks like you are giving a symbol as input, not a value. If you maintain the `<selection-help>` inside across, it is not a symbol/object it is a character vector, and the character vector does not have ambiguity (because it is not a symbol). The principle is the same as `f(1)`. I hope this gives some clarity. A note is that as soon as we evaluate the input it is no longer `.` but its real value.
You can see this by adding `print(x)` before quoting `x`.
You can read more about this in the advanced R programing https://adv-r.hadley.nz/ mainly chapter 7 to understand environments in R quoting, promises, and evaluations in the Metaprogramming section.

Comment: I do not think this answers the question. The question is not why this message occurs in general. The question here is why the placement of the selection helper matters. The example I gave in the question does not reference any external vector unless the placement of the selection helper affects its value. But why would piping the helper into across() versus typing it inside the parentheses affect this?

Comment: It does in fact answer exactly why this is happening. The piping process gives the next function an input called `.`. Evaluating a selection helper itself just returns a vector as an argument to `.cols`. This is the basic principle of `R` pipes and inputs. You can test this out with `rlang::quo`. if `f <- function(x) rlang::quo(x)` Running `f(1)` is different from running `1 %>% f`. First returns a quote `1` the second returns a quoted `.`.

Comment: That comment answers the question, but the answer does not include the content of that comment. If you update the answer, I can accept it. The pipe is what is different about the two examples in the question, so an answer should address that difference.

Comment: I would appreciate more clarity on the difference between piping and not piping if you have time to clarify. For example, I am not sure what “Evaluating a selection helper itself just returns a vector as an argument to `.cols`” contributes to the explanation. I thought the point of your comment was that evaluating the selection helper returns something different in the two contexts.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it brings some clarity. I also put a reference where you can get more in-depth reading on the topic.